# CosmosDb table store functions never returning

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure WebApp (C#/MVC) that I am trying to integrate a CosmosDb table store into. I added the nuget package for "WindowsAzure.Storage-PremiumTable" and added the code below to access a table and create if it does not yet exists.

```
string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[myAccountName];AccountKey=[myAccountKey];TableEndpoint=https://[myAccountName].documents.azure.com";
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");
table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

I stepped thru this code and all is fine until it got to the CreateIfNotExists. When I step over this function it never returns. I let it sit over an hour and it never came back. I tried it without the debugger involved and it still never returned. I also tried adding try/catch logic around this block of code, but there were no exceptions thrown.

I then went to the CosmosDb site and forked the sample application for this operation and ran it only changing the connectionstring to have my account details and it worked fine.  I copy/pasted the above code into the main() function of the sample app and it still worked.

This lead me to think that it has something to do with a bad interaction with something that is present in my webApp.

I copied the above code snippet into the Application_Start method in the Global.asax so it would be executed before many other things come into play and surprisingly it worked.

I then moved the code into a controller action and triggered that action (in this case, have the site present the login page to the user) and again the CreateIfNotExists call fails to return.

Just to add some additional things I tried, I also replaced the CreateIfNotExists with a request for a row from the people table (which exists and the row is viewable in the DataExplorer on the Azure management portal). However, this also exhibits the same issue as calling CreateIfNotExists which is to never return from the call.

So, I next decided to get the rest of my WebApp out of the picture, so I created a brand-new MVC WebApp in VS2017, added the "WindowsAzure.Storage-PremiumTable" nuget package (v 0.1.0-preview), then updated all packages to the most current (except for Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB since the PremiumTable package currently is only compatible with v 1.14.0 of DocumentDb). I added the above code snippet into the index method of the home controller and started the app up in the debugger. Again, the CreateIfNotExists did not return.

This is leading me to think that there is some incompatibility between ASP.NET MVC applications and the WindowsAzure.Storage-PremiumTable nuget package.

To further test this theory, I created a brand-new Console Application (.Net Framework), added the PremiumTables nuget package, pasted the above code snippet into the main() method and the CreateIfNotExists came back in about 1 second as normal.

I just wanted to put this out there in case anyone else is having the issue.  Plus I am hoping to get the appropriate attention of the internal Microsoft devs to figure this out since the PremiumTable package is not opensource so I could not step into it to try to help diagnose the issue further.

[UPDATE] as Camillo pointed out, there may be issues with using the synchronous API calls from within ASP.NET applications. So, switching to the async versions of the call will alleviate the issue.

Comment: Please add the method signature and how you are calling that method when it fails to return. I'm 99% sure you are either getting a deadlock or a context switch. BTW, there's nothing like ASP.NET incompatibility with CosmosDB. I'm creating an application against CosmosDB right now

Comment: I provided the full code snippet in the post.  The only thing that needs to be changed are the connectionstring account information.  As you will notice from the code snippet I'm calling table.CreateIfNotExists with no parameters.

Comment: No, you did not provided what I requested. Without the method signature (public void DoSomething....) and how you call it (x.DoSomething...) we cannot know where's the problem

Comment: the code snippet provided does not require any outside parameters. Everything needed is there. The function that does not return has 2 parameters that both have default values of null. I am not passing any parameters, so it will use null for both.

Comment: The fact that you can that the method works at application startup (which runs synchronously) but not elsewhere suggests that there is a synchronization/threading issue. I don't care about the parameters but the method definition itself (is it void, async void, Task or async Task?), how you call it (with/without await) and from where (Controller, class, static class?).

Comment: as mentioned in the post, the code snippet is dropped into the controller action as is. It's not a function called within the action. I physically copied the code snippet above into the controller action method with no changes except to add the private info into the connection string.

Comment: Once again, is the controller action defined as: void, async void, Task, async Task or what?

Comment: The boilerplate controller actions are created as "public ActionResult Index()". As I mentioned, I did not change anything but pasting the code snippet into the method.

Comment: Then try this: make the method an `async Task<IActionResult>` and use `await table.CreateIfNoteExistsAsync()`

Comment: I specifically wrote `CreateTableIfNotExistsAsync`, please read what I comment properly before replying

Comment: Ok, that did work, but doesn't this show that there is an issue with the synchronous version of the method?

Comment: Not necessarily. ASP.NET MVC's Controller Actions use specific contextdata, and since CreateTableIfNotExists most likely is calling CreateTableIfNotExistsAsync, then CreateTableIfNotExists cannot pass the Async version the request context so that it can go back to the same thread. When you use the async/await pattern, ASP.NET can go back to the context so that the processing can finish.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - why not post as an answer? These comments are turning into a discussion (which is not what comments are for), which you could easily move to [chat](chat.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented on the question, the problem is a deadlock most likely caused by a context switch.

To prevent that, you need to change this:

```
public IActionResult Hello()
{
    string connectionString = "something here";
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");
    table.CreateIfNotExists();
}
```

For this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Hello()
{
    string connectionString = "something here";
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");
    await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
}
```